# NSArrayController and referring to a shared, static, Core Data based library

Tags: cocoa, core-data, static-libraries, nsarraycontroller

Using [this](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/iphone-app-shared-libraries/) guide I have created a static library (let's call it *AppCore*) that can be shared between the Mac OS X and iOS versions of one app. This static library uses Core Data and the point of it is to share the model part and schema versioning between different implementations.

I created a `NSPersistentDocument` based project that will depend on this *AppCore*. In this project I added a reference to the .xcdatamodel file. Then I created a simple table view with add/remove buttons to edit an array of one entity type with the assisted "new core data entity" item. This created an instance of `NSArrayController` and the required bindings for the add/remove behaviour.

Now, everything seems to work fine when I'm using the default class for the Core Data entities (`NSManagedObject`) and I'm able to add new rows using the +/- buttons. However, when I change the entity implementation class to a custom one, I'm getting an error

```
Failed to create new object
```

This seems to come from the `NSArrayController` and it seems to be unable to instantiate the required entity. I can, however, create one in the `NSPersistentDocument` subclass by:

```
[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SomeEntity" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]
```

What confuses me is why the instance of `NSArrayController` can't. If I understand correctly, the array controller is instructed to create an entity, not class and my guess is that the entities are created with the help of `NSEntityDescription` class. I could implement my own version of the array controller's `add:` but then again, it might be that here something is fundamentally wrong. I haven't touched the `init:`s and the custom entity class implementation is simply for convenience, to access the attributes directly.

I have tried changing the base SDK on the *AppCore* but without effect. Currently it uses the iOS version but I'm not sure how it should be. This is another question but if unrelated, I might ask it here on a separate question.

So, to summarize, why can't the `NSArrayController` create an instance of this entity?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

This works if I add the `SomeEntity` class from the *AppCore* to the dependent project as a reference. This is not the most usable way since modifications to the *AppCore* has to be propagated to the dependatnt projects also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bingo. I missed the "-ObjC" flag for the dependant project's "other linker flags". Now everything works like a charm.